New software store not showing up in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I upgraded Ubuntu from Ubuntu 22.4.4 to Ubuntu 24.4.1 everything seems to work fine. But the new software store is not showing up, Ubuntu Software is showing up.
run sudo snap refresh
All snaps are up to date
they still don't appear
The Ubuntu 22 store appears, the new Ubuntu 24 store does not appear, even the icon is from Ubuntu 22.
I am very sorry to do an update like this.
I am more of an install from scratch person, I don't know what happened, now it doesn't even update the repositories. I had some really weird ones!!
What a disaster! I don't know what to do!!!
It's a disaster to update like this!!!
Now I get this:
When I try to update, this appears
E: Entry 1 incorrectly specified in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
E: Could not read source lists.
This was fixed by making the two files exactly the same.
edited as administrator
1 third.party.sources
2 third.party.sources.save
The new store is now showing up.
sudo killall snap-store
sudo snap refresh snap-store
Well, Ubuntu 24.04.1 is starting to work fine.
The update was done from Ubuntu 22.4.4.
In Settings-Ubuntu Desktop the enhanced tiling option did not appear.
apt install gnome-shell-extensions-ubuntu-tiling 46-1 ubuntu1.1
I rebooted and that option was already there.
Humble recommendation before doing this type of update
1- uninstall all third-party repositories along with their applications.
:)

App Center is the name of store, If you do not see it close the store and run sudo snap refresh in a terminal-

Thanks Amar. But as I close the store, I already ran sudo snap refresh, and nothing

What is the answer you got from sudo snap refresh if it is any other than All snaps up to date. edit your question with the result. do not answer it in comment.

What doesn't appear? Can you add a picture?

This command worked for me:
sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-24.04

I had to kill the existing snap-store process instance using the System Monitor app.

This does help, specially if you did a partial upgrade.

Run sudo killall snap-store if you get a similar error to: error: cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software), pids:        28632 

It worked for me:

First, ensure that snapd is installed by running:
sudo apt install snapd


Next, update Snap to the latest version:
sudo snap refresh


Finally, install the Snap Store:
sudo snap install snap-store



